# how to show details of current user from a related table in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a simple 1 user to many relationships database structure.

[image]

On my page I am able to use `<%= current_user.about %>` to get the about field for a current user. I would like to get the fields called followed_id and follower_id also for the current user (there may be many). Is there an easy way to do this on the page without calling the controller given there is only one current user?

Comment: `current_user.followed_id` and `current_user.follower_id`  ?

Comment: if only.... I get error undefined method `follower_id' for User

Comment: In that case, which of your models has `followed_id` and `follower_id` attributes, and what is its relationship to the `User` model? You might need to edit your question to clarify this as I don't think we have enough information to answer.

Comment: show the model `User` ...

Comment: Updated to show the table relationships

Comment: Ah now it makes sense! Are you sure `relationship` is the best name for a table in a **relational** database structure!? That's super confusing!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like:

```
<% current_user.relationships.pluck(:followed_id, :follower_id).each do |followed_id, follower_id|
  <%= # do some stuff with your followed_id and follower_id variables %>
<% end %>
```

(the `pluck` is just so that you only make a single call to your database, instead of one for each `relationship` - but there are other ways of doing this.)

---

If you can I would strongly consider renaming the `relationships` table, because that is really a very confusing name for a relational database. It's like having a table called `table` with columns called `column`, `row`, and `select`.

Comment: It's easily done. I once wrote an error tracking app in which I tried to use the ruby class `Error` as an active record model...insanity ensued.